# R plotting fuction returns a plot with numbers everywhere

Tags: r, plot, forecast

This is my first post to the site. I have been working on a project where I forecast mortality rates for different countries. I made use of the demography package in R.
Here are the lines of code I use to plot some results:

```
plot(e0(country1, series=group1, years = 1950:max(forecast.country1$LC$year)))

lines(x= forecast.dxt$year, y=e0(forecast.country1$LC)$mean, col="red") 

lines(x= forecast.dxt$year, y=e0(forecast.dxt)$mean, col="blue") 

lines(x= forecast.dxt$year, y=e0(forecast.period)$mean, col="green")
```

This worked fine until earlier today when a funny thing started happening. Please see the attached image for reference. I have no idea why it happens. When I swich off my computer for a while and return it produces plots that look fine for a while and then it reverts back to producing these gibberish things.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Start Overflow. More details are needed to help you. First, you don't show all the code used for plotting. This would be helpful. Second, explain, how do you run the plotting, manually or in a loop. Where the data come from? Can you show some example of the data?

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?